# Can i see my Bluetooth connection as network interface in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, bluetooth, network-interface

I have 2 laptops. I have paired them successfully with each other via Bluetooth, so I can exchange files between each other.

Both of my laptops have Linux installed. when I run the `ifconfig` command to see the network interfaces, my Bluetooth interface is not shown.

Is there any way that this Bluetooth connection between my 2 laptops, can be shown as a network interface, so I can send files there via command line (for testing purposes)?

Comment: Do you have BlueZ v4 or v5?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can run Ethernet over Bluetooth ([BNEP](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/BNEP.aspx)) using a [PAN](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/PAN.aspx).

- For BlueZ 4, see the [HOWTO-PAN](http://bluez.sourceforge.net/contrib/HOWTO-PAN) documentation; basically, run `pand` on both devices and you'll get a `bnep0` interface on both. (If I remember correctly, one computer has to be in NAP or GN (controller) mode, all others in PANU (client) mode connecting to the controller device.)

  ```
  server:
    # pand --listen --role NAP --sdp

  client:
    # pand --connect 01:ab:23:cd:45:ef
  ```

  (The HOWTO is slightly outdated – you don't have to compile anything custom anymore; it's a native part of the kernel and BlueZ now.)
- For BlueZ 5, this is done using D-Bus calls to *bluetoothd*, e.g. using Blueman or [bt-pan](https://github.com/mk-fg/fgtk/blob/master/bt-pan):

  ```
  server:
    # ip link add br0 type bridge
    # ip link set br0 up
    $ bt-pan server br0

  client:
    $ bt-pan client 01:ab:23:cd:45:ef --wait
  ```

  See also http://blog.fraggod.net/2015/03/28/bluetooth-pan-network-setup-with-bluez-5x.html.

Note that Bluetooth also has its own file transfer mechanisms – ObexPush and ObexFTP.